# Can't post data from form with node.js

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, forms, post

I can't send data to mongodb database after submitting form. It works on website load, when i put connectDB function into app.use, then it executes it, but if i use app.post('/test') it doesn't execute this function.

Here is my js code:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const {MongoClient} = require("mongodb");
const app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
const port = 5000;
 
const url = 'connectionstring';
const dbName = "test";
const collName = "zad";
 
 
async function connectDB(){
    const client = new MongoClient(url, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
    try{
    await client.connect();
    const db = client.db(dbName);
    await insertData(db);
    }catch(error){
        console.error('blad', error);
    }
        finally{
    await client.close();
        }
}
 
async function insertData(db){
    const collection = db.collection(collName);
    const data1 = {name: "test2", lname: "test3"};
    const result = await collection.insertOne(data1);
}
 
app.use('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
 
app.post('/test', (req, res) => {
    connectDB();
});
 
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server runnin on " + port);
});
```

I know there might be a lot unnecessary code, but it shouldn't interfere with my actual problem.

Html form code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Strona testowa
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="/test">
            <label>Enter name</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="Enter first name" required>
            <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Enter last name" required>
            <input type="submit" value="Add">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The /test appears in website address at the end.